# Unable to load custom config in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a custom config living in

```
/home/me/www/mysite/config/searchService.php
```

which returns

```
return array('myConsumerKey' => 'superSecretStuff',
'baseUrl' => 'superSecretStuff');
```

I am using it in my controller

```
    $this->myConsumerKey = Config::get('searchService.myConsumerKey');
    $this->baseUrl = Config::get('searchService.baseUrl');
```

however both are returning null

I have tried...

- composer dump-autoload clear cache
- clearing cache
- adding file to my composer autoload
- file permissions on file are the same as other working configs
- Apache is the owner of the file

any other help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Just to check, you've tried: `php artisan config:clear` ?

Comment: Oh wait, this has now Worked!! To anyone looking at this I would recommend composer dump-autoload  & config:clear, if this still does not work, do the same two again just reversed. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5 you can use `config()` helper function.

`config('searchService.myConsumerKey');`

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I am afraid that even with that method it is still returning null, it for some reason is not being found :/

Comment: please check the path with `dd(\Config::get('searchService.php'))` .